# Populate dropdown from return function Razor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to populate a dropdown box with values from a database tables using EF
Firstly I'm not sure about the return values here 
Description is a string so I',m returning a List but this does not work..
Secondly not how the return values can be used to populate the dropdown in my razor page view
any guidance appreciated
In webforms it was just a databind to the control this seems rather complicated

```
 public List<string> getEstablishments()
        {
            var db = new mydbContext();
            result=db.TblEstablishment.Select(x => new { x.Description }).ToList();

            db.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Change your select statement to `Select(x => x.Description).ToList()`. The way it is now you are creating an anonymous object and returning that instead of a string.

Comment: thanks! thats returning the List now properly

Answer (score 1):

Change your select statement to `Select(x => x.Description).ToList()`. The way it is now you are creating an anonymous object and returning that instead of a string. For binding the establishment in a dropdown you can do the below:

```
public class EstablishmentOptionView
{
    public int EstablishmentId { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
}

public List<EstablishmentOptionView> getEstablishments()
{
            var db = new mydbContext();
            result=db.TblEstablishment.Select(x => new EstablishmentOptionView {EstablishmentId = x.Id, Description = x.Description }).ToList();

            db.Dispose();
            return result;
 }

//somewhere else 
SomeDropDownList.DataValueField = "EstablishmentId";
SomeDropDownList.DataTextField = "Description";
SomeDropDownList.DataSource = getEstablishments();
SomeDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: there's not DataBinds/Razor in MVC?

Comment: Oh sorry I read Webforms in the question and thought you needed databinding in that form.

Answer (score 1):

In Razor:

```
//in your code, myEstablishments would be passed in somehow
List<string> _myEstablishments = new List<string> {"one", "two"};
@Html.DropDownList(name: "myDropDownList", selectList: _myEstablishments.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s });
```

Comment: the "name:" wasnt needed but once I passed the list from my funtion your command worked.....@Html.DropDownList("name",selectList: getEstablishments().Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s }));